# Calculating the amount of dissolved gases in a liquid?

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure, equilibrium

The most basic situation, water at room temperature, has dissolved oxygen, CO2, and more. Why is this? How would one calculate how much gas *should* be dissolved in any given liquid?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect this is more physical chemistry than physics, and the mods may well migrate the question. Until then ...

See the Wikipedia entry on [Henry's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henry%27s_law) for a discussion on calculating the solubility of gases. Henry's law is phenomenological, that is it gives a macroscopic equation for calculating the solubility without going into the microscopic details of how gases dissolve. You just need to know the enthalpy of solution.

It's hard to generalise about the microscopic origin of gas solubility. Molecules of, for example, oxygen will interact with molecules of water just as any two molecules interact. You'd expect a long range attractive force and a short range repulsive force. The enthalpy of solution is (loosely) the energy change in moving a molecule of oxygen from the gas phase into the solution. How big the energy change is and what sign it is will depend on the solvent and the gas. Generally speaking the entropy of solution is negative i.e. the entropy of the gas is lower in the solution than in the gas, so you don't get high solubility unless the gas and solvent interact strongly (and attractively). For example carbon dioxide and water react to form carbonic acid, so [carbon dioxide](http://encyclopedia.airliquide.com/encyclopedia.asp?LanguageID=11&GasID=26) is pretty soluble in water. [Oxygen](http://encyclopedia.airliquide.com/encyclopedia.asp?LanguageID=11&GasID=48) is a lot less soluble, and [neon](http://encyclopedia.airliquide.com/Encyclopedia.asp?GasID=46#GeneralData) is even less soluble.